# noHandlerFound Spring : Rest Service with Spring 5.x Security to Support JWT (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm getting this error when try to access the path .

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/portal/auth] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I am trying to update my application to support Spring Security. I am using  Hibernate and in-memory database(HSQLDB). 
This is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.portal.employee")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    @Autowired
    JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Value("${jwt.route.authentication.path}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                // Un-secure H2 Database
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/portal/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
                .cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        authenticationPath
                )

                // allow anonymous resource requests
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                )

                // Un-secure H2 Database (for testing purposes, H2 console shouldn't be unprotected in production)
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");
    }
}
```

My AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer Configuration

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class < ? > [] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
                ApplicationConfiguration.class, HibernateConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class < ? > [] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {
                "/portal/*"
        };
    }
}
```

Hibernate Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setConfigLocation(context.getResource("classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Employee.class, Authority.class, User.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```